# A text inside a movieclip prevents the user to click

Tags: actionscript-3

There is a movieclip which has several animated frames inside itself. It is going to be played when the movieclip is clicked. I did not get any error using `eventlistener` and `event.target.play()`. Everything was OK.

The problem started when I put some text inside the movieclip. When the user clicks the movieclip's texted area, the software gives me this error:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property play not found on flash.text.TextField and there is no default value.
>       at Adsız_1_fla::MainTimeline/oynat()

However, when the user clicks the area that is far to the text, the movieclip is played without any problem.

Comment: Use **Event.currentTarget** property to figure what was clicked, not **Event.target** (read here why: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#currentTarget). Alternately, set the **.mouseEnabled = false;** for that **TextField** instance so it won't interact with the mouse.

Comment: Thank you Organis. Event.currentTarget property solved the problem.